# Sharing components between modules

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, module

In my project, I have the main app module, which has dependencies on submodules I added for my project, let's say one is for a custom alert dialog, another for custom views, etc...

How can I get a reference of a value in a submodule from the main app module?
As an example, the custom alert dialog which has a layout xml needs to take a color value which is found in the main app module.

I tried to add the main app module as a dependency in the submodule but that definitely won't work since there will be a circular dependency.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

## Explanation:

Try to organise submodules with next rules:

**1).** *Main app module* with `Activity`, `Fragment` + `xmlayouts`

No modules must depend on this module. This module will depend on ***resource module, submodule 1, submodule 2.***

Don't store any shared values in this module like `colors`, `dimens` etc.

**2).** *Resource module* with `colors`, `attrs`, `dimens` etc.

Just create android library module and store here only shared resources. This module must have no dependencies. And each module which needs resources will depend on this module.

**3).** *Submodule 1* with custom alerts.

This module will depend on ***resource module***.

**4).** *Submodule 2* with custom views.

This module will depend on ***resource module***.

## Diagram:

[image]

## Code:

https://github.com/AlexanderGarmash/AndroidModulesShowcase

## Description:

`<module_root>/app/build.gradle` dependencies section:

```
compile project (':ResourceModule')
compile project (':Submodule1')
compile project (':Submodule2')
```

`<module_root>/ResourceModule/build.gradle` dependencies section:

nothing

`<module_root>/Submodule1/build.gradle` dependencies section:

```
compile project (':ResourceModule')
```

`<module_root>/Submodule2/build.gradle` dependencies section:

```
compile project (':ResourceModule')
```

## Advantages:

- Low coupling
- Transparent clear structure

## Disadvantages:

- If you have a lot of modules you need to not forget link to `ResourceModule` everywhere.

## UPDATE

Don't forget to import correct `R` class.
[image]

Comment: After I moved all resources (except layouts), the colors in my drawables which were referencing values which were generated in the build folder are not present (such as @color/black or @color/md_brown_800). Those are the values automatically generated in build, not set by me of course.
How do I solve this issue?

Comment: @RJFares It's pretty simple. In `import` you should check that you import `R` class from target module, not from current module. Because `R` class is generated for every module

Comment: @RJFares, for example for resource module it will be `com.garmash.example.resource.lib.R`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100758/discussion-between-rjfares-and-alexander).

Comment: what if I want to add a image in the new module, how do I access that image then?

Comment: if I follow this, how can we avoid resource values getting replaced by other defined values from other libraries?  

 for example, suppose that I have a string value in the 'ResourceModule' as 'string_1' .


'ResourceModule'    will have a string value  'string_1'  => 'value1'

'SomeLibrary'    will have a string value  'string_1'  => 'value2'

so if add both these dependencies to the 'app' module, which value will survive, then these string files are merged 
during the runtime?

Comment: I'd like to know where'd you find these rules?

Answer (score 3):

You should add the resources values in library module instead of app module if you want to use them in library. Because when adding a library, app can use library's resources but vice versa can not be.

Comment: what should I add in the gradle file then? @Bhawna