# Android Clean Architecture - correct way to access Resource strings

Tags: android, repository, android-resources, clean-architecture

I like Clean architecture however something that has always troubled me is the access to Resource files across layers.

I know that layers other than the View layer shouldn't have references to anything related to Android SDK. But there are times where specific texts need to be managed and it becomes a headache the further the layer goes.

Specifically, I have the following scenario which made me uncertain on how to implement correctly:

*When the screen is opened, a warning message should be presented. This warning message may be retrieved from a remote source according to a flag or taken from a local string if the flag is off.*

As I understand, the presenter shouldn't mind the value of the flag and simply call UseCase.getWarningMessage(). Going deeper, the UseCase should probably only take the flag value and send it to the repository (I'm still not sure if the flag should be instead accessed directly in the Repository).

After that, the repository would check the flag and retrieve the remote message or simply take it from the local strings.

At this point, how could the repository take the Resource string? Should dependency be sent all the way to the Repository layer in case it needs access to resources? Should the presenter instead be the responsibility of managing the flag to know if warning messages should be retrieved remotely or locally?

Answer (score 0):

"...layers other than the View layer shouldn't have references to anything related to Android SDK." is simply wrong. If some module/class depends on some other module/class, it depends on that module/class. No way around it.

What you should not do with Android is that your non-UI modules should not keep references of UI related objects (Activities, fragments, views) that otherwise prevent them from being garbage collected. However, when you need a **Context** in classes with application scope - like repository classes which are implemented in the way recommended by android - it is totally OK to use application **Context**s.

**EDIT**
**Since you ask that question, I am assuming you are not using a dependency injection framework.**

You probably follow developer guides, and implementing your repository as an Singleton. Now a simple way of passing an ApplicationContext instance could be:
1. Define a static field of type **android.app.Application** inside your repository class. Provide a setter to inject that dependency.

```
public class MyRepo {
   private static Application application;
   ..................

   public static void injectApplication(Application app) {
        if(null == application) {
            application = app;
        }
   }
}
```

May be you can document your class on to call this new method prior to any **getInstance()** method usage.

2. Extend android.app.Application class. Override **onCreate()** and inject 'this' to repository.

```
public class MyApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        MyRepo.injectApplication(this);
    }
.........
}
```

3. Do not forget to modify your manifest file for your new Application class.

Comment: And so how is Repository supposed to get the Application Context? from an Application instance?

Comment: As of today with jetpack compose you won't need that workaround anymore, just use [stringResource()](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/resources#strings).
I will try to make the question clearer for you.
When you do clean architecture the data layer does not know anything from the presentation layer.
We have two modules. First one with the app, activities, ... and most important the resources. This first one would be the presentation layer.
Second one which needs a string resource from the first one. This second one may be the data layer.

Now how to access resources?

Answer (score 0):

Your second question seems like the correct answer to described usecase, but let me first answer the other two questions.

> Should the presenter instead be the responsibility of managing the flag to know if warning messages should be retrieved remotely or locally?

Absolutely not!

> At this point, how could the repository take the Resource string?

An extra module just holding ressources is a way to achieve this. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34808917/10225673).

But still this is somehow breaking the layers.

> Should dependency be sent all the way to the Repository layer in case it needs access to resources?

If the flag is hardcoded in the presentation layer. The flag and or the string need to be passed down all the way.

And here i see the design problem:

> This warning message may be retrieved from a remote source according to a flag or taken from a local string if the flag is off.

This flag should be part of the model. And when you change the flag it goes all the  way down to the repository where it will be needed. Then the repository can decide by the flag if it needs to retreive it from remote or just use the local string, which should now be hosted by the repository module.